# Setting an offline page for flex application

Tags: apache-flex, app-offline.htm

I have a flex application which when am publishing a new version for, would like to take it offline and present the user with a page that explains that the site is under construction and will be back in a few minutes. Is there a way to setup something like that in a flex application?
I have done it before for an asp application and would like to be able to do the same sort of thing for my flex application.
Thank you.

Comment: Do the same thing you did in your asp.

Comment: It depends on your web server. I do this all the time but its part of my powershell script for my web server (IIS). We keep an extra HTML page in the directory and rename it to the main HTML file, while we go into "maintenance mode".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an AIR app, you could use set up a poll using the [ServiceMonitor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/net/ServiceMonitor.html) class. That class will allow you to ping your domain at a predetermined interval to check for connectivity. If it comes back with a Status Event with status "Service.unavailable", you know your site is down. From there, you could possibly use the [PopupManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html) class to throw a new component above your app that prevents the user from interacting with the underlying application; your "offline page".

Comment: Unfortunately its not an air application. Is there a way i could do for a normal flex application? I cannot do the same thing that i have done in asp because i have more than one solution in a folder. Therefore if a user points to another html file. They will potentially be able to run another swf. Thank you.